# How do I decode a CGI form?

Tags: perl, forms, cgi

How do I decode a CGI form in Perl?

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Your exact title is in [perlfaq9](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html)'s answer to [How do I decode a CGI form?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How_do_I_decode_a_CG). There's a lot of good stuff in the Perl documentation that's just sitting there waiting for you to read it. :)

Comment: Importing perlfaq into SO (using a designated perlfaq user) might be a good idea.  It would be kind of a pain to keep updated, unless there's a nice SO API I don't know about.

Comment: I've asked on meta about importing the perlfaq, and the consensus seems to be that its a good idea. I just haven't done it yet. There's no API as far as I know, but I wrote a test script to create SO posts so I could automate it myself.